# Google Apps Script HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a simple html form with email sending

this is the html file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function submitForm() {
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var comment = document.getElementById('comment').value;
        
        /**
         * First run submitData(name, email, comment) function of Code.gs
         * Then, run showMessage(value) function of this html file
         */
        google.script.run
              .withSuccessHandler(showMessage) // execute showMessage(value) function on success
              .submitData(name, email, comment); // call submitData(name, email, comment) function present in Code.gs file
      }
      
      function showMessage(value) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = value;
        document.getElementById('name').value = '';
        document.getElementById('email').value = '';
        document.getElementById('comment').value = '';
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Feedback Form</h2>
    <div id="message" style="color:green"></div>
    <p><input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name"><p>
    <p><input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Your Email"></p>
    <p><textarea id="comment" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea></p>
    <p><button onclick="submitForm(); return false;">Submit</button></p>    
  </body>
</html>
```

and this is the gs file:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html')
    .setTitle("Simple HTML Form Example");
}
 
function submitData(name, email, comment) {
  var subject = 'New Feedback';
  var body = 'Name: ' + name + '<br> Email: ' + email + '<br> Comment: ' + comment;
  var to = 'my-email@email.com'; // EMAIL ADDRESS WHERE THE FEEDBACK EMAIL IS SENT
  MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: to,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: body
    }); 
  
  return 'Feedback Sent!';
}
```

I'm looking for a formula to view the edited fields name, email, instead of the text "Feedback Sent!"

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML Email Form**

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function submitForm(form) {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(value){
          document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = value;
          document.getElementById('name').value = '';
          document.getElementById('email').value = '';
          document.getElementById('comment').value = '';
        }) 
        .submitData(form);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Feedback Form</h2>
    <div id="message" style="color:green"></div>
    <form>
    <br /><input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
    <br /><input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
    <br /><textarea id="comment" rows="10" cols="40" name="comment"></textarea>
    <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm(this.parentNode);" />  
  </form>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Google Script:

```
function submitData(form) {
  var subject='New Feedback';
  var body=Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment);
  var to = 'my-email@email.com'; 
  MailApp.sendEmail({to: to,subject: subject,htmlBody: body}); 
  //Logger.log('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment);
  return Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment);
}
//It works as a dialog
function showTheDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq7');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Emails")
}
```

[image]

[image]

I didn't actually test it with the mailapp line. I just used the Logger and saw that it returned the feedback message.

Comment: Use GmailApp  instead.

Comment: Ok thanks mr. Cooper, now I can't test because I have reached the maximum sending limit (100) so I have to wait about another 2 hours.
As soon as I can test it I will inform you
For now, thank you.

Comment: Thanks mr. Cooper, your formula works perfectly, it's really cool.
Now I continue with my implementation, at the end of it I will try to show you maybe you will give me a judgment.

Comment: Hello mr. Cooper, I have submitted another request you can find it here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59617795/google-apps-script-custom-html-form-data-to-spreadsheet-convert-save-pdf-and-sen Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: It is a working example but not as a web app.  I built to run as a dialog because then I don't require doGets or doPosts

Comment: How to run it as a dialog @MetaMan then?  I tried to simply "Run" it, but get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

Comment: You run the `showTheDialog()`.  It's the only logical choice since it's the only one without parameters.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out eventually. Sorry for these noob questions.