# Google app script on how to create a pdf from the data received from an html form of its spreadsheet and send the pdf file via email

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script

Google app script on how to create a pdf from the data received from an html form of your spreadsheet and send the pdf file via email - I would like to create a pdf file from the data recorded on the worksheet via a custom html form

I have a simple html form with email sending

**this is the index html FORM file:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function submitForm(form) {
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(value){
          document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = value;
          document.getElementById('name').value = '';
          document.getElementById('email').value = '';
          document.getElementById('comment').value = '';
        }) 
        .submitData(form);
      }
    </script>
    <?!= include("css");?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Feedback Form</h2>
    <div id="message"></div>

    <br /><input id="button-responder" style="display:none;" type ="button" onclick="submitResponder();" value = "Nuova iscrizione">

    <form id="my-form">
    <br /><input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
    <br /><input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
    <br /><textarea id="comment" rows="10" cols="40" name="comment"></textarea>
    <br /><input id="btn" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm(this.parentNode),document.getElementById('my-form').style.display='none',submitResponder('button-responder');" />
  </form>
  <?!= include("test-js");?>  
  </body>
</html>
```

this Google Script with alias email:

```js
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate();//not all caps but it has to match the name of the file and it doesn't - Change to PAGE
}

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}


function submitData(form) {
  
  var subject='New Feedback';
  var body=Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment);

  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
   Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
   Logger.log(aliases[0]); //returns the alias located at position 0 of the aliases array

  GmailApp.sendEmail('my-email@my-email.com','From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': aliases[0],subject: subject,htmlBody: body});

  return Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment);

  
}


function userClicked(userInfo){
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/x/xx-xx-xxx_-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxx/edit#gid=x";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
    ws.appendRow([userInfo.name, userInfo.email, userInfo.comment]);
}
```

this is custom javascript file ("test-js"):

```js
<script>

function submitResponder() {
  var x = document.getElementById("button-responder");
  var xx = document.getElementById("my-form");
  var xxx = document.getElementById("message");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    xx.style.display = "none";
    xxx.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    xx.style.display = "block";
    xxx.style.display = "none";
  }
}


document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);
  
  function doStuff(){
   var userInfo = {}
   userInfo.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   userInfo.email = document.getElementById("email").value;
   userInfo.comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
   
   google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
   document.getElementById("name").value= "";
   document.getElementById("email").value= "";
   document.getElementById("comment").value= "";   
  
}
</script>
```

this is a simply css style file ("css"):

```css
<style>

#message {
 color: red;
}

</style>
```

I'm looking for a formula to create a pdf file by taking the data entered in the forms and send it by email.
The file must be created in a specific folder / subfolder in drive.
The name of the file must replay the "name" field edited on the form.

Now the most important part.
I would like the link of the pdf file to appear only on the html page and not in the email,
as shown in the example below:

```js
return Utilities.formatString ('name:% s <br /> Email:% s <br /> Comment:% s', form.name, form.email, form.comment)
link to PDF file
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

> **NEW QUESTION!!**

In relation to the function described below:

```js
function submitData(form) {
  var subject='New Feedback';
  var body=Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment);

  var folderId = "my-folder-ID"; // Please set the folder ID.  // Added
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(body, MimeType.HTML, form.name).getAs(MimeType.PDF);  // Added
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob);  // Added

  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
   Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
   Logger.log(aliases[0]); //returns the alias located at position 0 of the aliases array

  GmailApp.sendEmail('my-email@my-email.com','From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': aliases[0],subject: subject,htmlBody: body, attachments: [blob]});  // Modified

//  return file.getUrl();  // Modified
  return Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s<br />PDF: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment,file.getUrl());
}
```

I am looking for I'm trying to return in a generic test format of the type "see your PDF file" clickable, instead of the URL address, in the function:

```js
return Utilities.formatString ('name:% s <br /> Email:% s <br /> Comment:% s <br /> PDF:% s', form.name, form.email, form.comment, file. getUrl ());
```

I wish I could use a basic document as a template for the style of creating the PDF file similar to this:
https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2018/09/17/auto-fill-google-doc-from-google-form-submission/
Keep in mind that my application is a custom html form as you can see from the place above.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you explain about `spreadsheet` in your title? I cannot understand about the relationship between `spreadsheet` in your title and your goal.

Comment: Google app script on how to create a pdf from the data received from an html form of its spreadsheet and send the pdf file via email - I would like to create a pdf file from the data recorded on spresdsheet through a custom html form - "sorry for my bad english" -

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. Unfortunately, I cannot still see the vision of your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this. For example, can you provide the sample input and output you expect?

Comment: I have provided you with all the code to test the script application, the files described above.
What is missing, what I am looking for, is the function to create the pdf file from the data entered in the custom html form.

Comment: This question of mine is an evolution of this topic of mine:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583876/google-apps-script-html-form

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your question is unrelated to Spreadsheet, and you want to create `Utilities.formatString ('name:% s <br /> Email:% s <br /> Comment:% s', form.name, form.email, form.comment)` to the specific folder as a PDF file. And also, you want to retrieve the link of created PDF file. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205477/discussion-between-dom-and-tanaike).

Comment: Exact!! The files that I have provided work just as well as they are.
Now the data entered in the form must also be converted into a pdf file, which will be saved in a specific folder / subfolder in drive, and simultaneously sent as an attachment to the email, while the link of the pdf file must be shown only in the html page together to the others.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that I could understand about your goal. I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to convert `var body=Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment);` as a PDF file.
- You want to put the created PDF file to the specific folder in Google Drive.
- You want to send the created PDF file as an attachment file.
- You want to retrieve the URL of created PDF file and return it to HTML side.
- Your question is unrelated to Spreadsheet.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your case, I think that your goal can be achieved by modifying `submitData()` at Google Apps Script side.
- When the button is pushed, create a PDF data from `var body=Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment);`. And create the PDF data as the file.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `submitData()` as follows. Please set the folder ID to `var folderId = "###"`.

```
function submitData(form) {
  var subject='New Feedback';
  var body=Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment);

  var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID.  // Added
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(body, MimeType.HTML, form.name).getAs(MimeType.PDF);  // Added
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob);  // Added

  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
   Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
   Logger.log(aliases[0]); //returns the alias located at position 0 of the aliases array

  GmailApp.sendEmail('my-email@my-email.com','From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': aliases[0],subject: subject,htmlBody: body, attachments: [blob]});  // Modified

  return file.getUrl();  // Modified
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to modify the style of PDF file, please modify `name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s` of `var body=Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment);`. You can use HTML in this case.
- By the situation, it might be required to share the created PDF file.

#### References:

- [Class Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities)
- [Class DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)
- [getAs(contentType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getascontenttype)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Tanaike. The result is very close to what I was looking for.
Some things are missing, such as in the result of the heml page there is only the link to the file, the other data are missing (name, email, comment).
Is there a way we can communicate so we can show you screenshots ??

Comment: For my writing error, I was trying to save the pdf file in a folder / subfolder in drive.
To change the style of the pdf I tried to use a basic document for the pdf template.

Comment: @Dom Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. If you want to return the URL and `form.name,form.email,form.comment`, how about modifying from `return file.getUrl()` to `return Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s<br />URL: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment,file.getUrl());`?

Comment: Perfect Mr. Tanaike.Thank you very much!!
Now I study how to make the link (pdf file) clickable and display a generic text instead of the url. And still how to create a basic template for the PDF style, but if you kindly want to help me I would be grateful.

Comment: @Dom Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your trying, when you have the issue for it, please post your issue by including the detail information as new question. We will support to resolve your issue.