# Google App Script generate a clickable link to pdf by my-drive

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

In relation from my post:

[Google app script on how to create a pdf from the data received from an html form of its spreadsheet and send the pdf file via email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59617795/9519917)

In relation to the function described below:

```js
function submitData(form) {
  var subject='New Feedback';
  var body=Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment);

  var folderId = "my-folder-ID"; // Please set the folder ID.  // Added
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(body, MimeType.HTML, form.name).getAs(MimeType.PDF);  // Added
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob);  // Added

  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
   Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
   Logger.log(aliases[0]); //returns the alias located at position 0 of the aliases array

  GmailApp.sendEmail('my-email@my-email.com','From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': aliases[0],subject: subject,htmlBody: body, attachments: [blob]});  // Modified

//  return file.getUrl();  // Modified
  return Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s<br />PDF: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment,file.getUrl());
}
```

I am looking for I'm trying to return in a generic test format of the type "see your PDF file" clickable, instead of the URL address, in the function:

```js
return Utilities.formatString ('name:% s <br /> Email:% s <br /> Comment:% s <br /> PDF:% s', form.name, form.email, form.comment, file. getUrl ());
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to modify `PDF: %s` to the clickable text of `see your PDF file`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
return Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s<br />PDF: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment,file.getUrl());
```

#### To:

```
return Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s<br />PDF: <a target="_blank" href="%s">see your PDF file</a>', form.name,form.email,form.comment,file.getUrl());
```

- By above modification, when you click the button, you can see `PDF: see your PDF file` which has the clickable text. And when you click "see your PDF file", the PDF file is opened.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Dom Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.