# Google App Script create a file PDF from document template base

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script, google-forms

In relation to my post:

[Google app script on how to create a pdf from the data received from an html form of its spreadsheet and send the pdf file via email](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59617795/9519917)

In relation to the function described below:

```js
function submitData(form) {
  var subject='New Feedback';
  var body=Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment);

  var folderId = "my-folder-ID"; // Please set the folder ID.  // Added
  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(body, MimeType.HTML, form.name).getAs(MimeType.PDF);  // Added
  var file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob);  // Added

  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
   Logger.log(aliases); //returns the list of aliases you own
   Logger.log(aliases[0]); //returns the alias located at position 0 of the aliases array

  GmailApp.sendEmail('my-email@my-email.com','From an alias', 'A message from an alias!', {'from': aliases[0],subject: subject,htmlBody: body, attachments: [blob]});  // Modified

//  return file.getUrl();  // Modified
  return Utilities.formatString('name: %s <br />Email: %s<br />Comment: %s<br />PDF: %s', form.name,form.email,form.comment,file.getUrl());
}
```

I would like use a document as a base template for creating a PDF file similar to this one:
https://jeffreyeverhart.com/2018/09/17/auto-fill-google-doc-from-google-form-submission/
How can I accomplish this with my application? Which is a custom html form as you can see from above.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: I wish I could use a basic document as a template for the style of creating the PDF - sorry for my bad english -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to create a PDF file using the template of Google Document.
- You want to set `form.name,form.email,form.comment` the template Document, and then, you want to export it as the PDF file.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- At first, please prepare a Google Document which is used as the template.
- When there is the template Document, at first, copy the template Document and replace the values for replacing with `form.name,form.email,form.comment`. Then, the Document is converted to the PDF data.

#### Usage:

Before you run the script, please prepare a Google Document which is used as the template.

In this case, `{{name}}`, `{{email}}` and `{{comment}}` are replaced with `form.name`, `form.email` and `form.comment`, respectively. So please include `{{name}}`, `{{email}}` and `{{comment}}` in the template Document.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows. And please set the file ID of the template Google Document to `templateDocumentId`.

From:

```
var blob = Utilities.newBlob(body, MimeType.HTML, form.name).getAs(MimeType.PDF);
```

To:

```
var templateDocumentId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of the template Google Document

var docId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateDocumentId).makeCopy("temp").getId();
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docId);

// Please modify as follows.
// var body = doc.getBody();
// body.replaceText("{{name}}", form.name).replaceText("{{email}}", form.email).replaceText("{{comment}}", form.comment);
doc.getBody().replaceText("{{name}}", form.name).replaceText("{{email}}", form.email).replaceText("{{comment}}", form.comment); // Modified

doc.saveAndClose();
var blob = doc.getBlob().setName(form.name);
DriveApp.getFileById(docId).setTrashed(true);
```

- In this modified script, the copied Document is moved to the trash box by the last line. So please be careful this.

#### Note:

- I'm not sure about the template Document you want to use. So if this modified script cannot be used for your template Document, can you provide it?

#### References:

- [makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname)
- [replaceText(searchPattern, replacement)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String))
- [setTrashed()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#settrashedtrashed)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Very cool Mr.Tanaike. The basic document as a template is perfect, but there is a small problem.
the body of the email displays this:
DocumentBodySection
The -name- and -email fields are gone.

Comment: @Dom Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your issue. So can you share the template Google Document for replicating your issue? If I could replicate your issue, I can think of the solution. Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: This is template google document:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lpgFtBP2ZTtz_XOrrQr96yIwXUVN2PvGuy4LyCtqC0E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This is email problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fi7XHsRVd7rx32nlu1TCCIKiM2O9bDyr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Dom Thank you for replying and sharing the information. I could understand about your issue. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? The reason of the issue is that the variable of `body` was used 2 times. This was my mistaken. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Why did you set it as trashed? Also the final doc is not a PDF and is not renamed in my case.

Comment: @Radek About your question of `Why did you set it as trashed? Also the final doc is not a PDF and is not renamed in my case.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your question. But I would like to support you. So in order to correctly understand about it, can you post it as an answer by including more information? By this, I would like to try to understand it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve it?

Comment: Tanaike, there is no issue. I was just pointing out that when I copied your code 1) it did not create PDF file and 2) it did no rename the final output file. I managed to accomplished what I needed with your code. The question title asked for PDF file so I was just pointing out that code in the answer did not create PDF for me.

Comment: @Radek Thank you for replying. At first, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About `1) it did not create PDF file`, in this case, the blob is directly used as the attachment file of `GmailApp.sendEmail`. About `2) it did no rename the final output file.`, if you want to set the filename of blob, please use `setName()`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#setName(String))

Comment: Your code was very very useful. Because of it I was able to achieve what I wanted.