# How do you run a function of the server side while on the client side?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, server-side, client-side

So I've been having this isue for several days now. I'm trying to pass data into my serverside script, but when I do I get this error message.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpKYn.png)

I've tried watching several videos on youtube and they all say the same thing, that you have to use google.script.run. The problem comes with the function that is called after the run. Here is a sample of the code im using.

```
function doGet() {
  var output = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index");
  output.content = "New string being passed";
  return output.evaluate();
}
function doUpload(data){
  logger.log(data);
  Logger.log("I was called!")
}
  
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title><?= content ?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1><?= content ?></h1>
   <div id="output"></div>
   <form>
   <input type="type" name="first" id="first" value="Laurence">
   <input type="button" id="subButton" value="submit">
   </form>
   <script>
   var output = document.getElementById("output");
   var first = document.getElementById("first");
   document.getElementById("subButton").addEventListener("click", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   output.innerHTML = first.value;
   var myData ={"first":first.value};
   console.log("hello");
   google.script.run.doUpload(myData);
   })
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see im trying to run doUpload(data) but it wont run. I already singed out of all my accounts as I though that could be the issue but it wasn't. Please help, thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should add the event listener after the html gets loaded like in window.onload.  It will probably work then

Comment: You use the [XMLHttpRequest with FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Using_a_formdata_event) on the Client-side to send and receive information from the Server.

Comment: @StackSlave I disagree `google.script.run.doUpload(myData);` should  do it.

Comment: Oh I'm assuming that you html is in a webapp.  Is that the case?

Comment: If that method is sending and receiving from the Server it's use the `XMLHttpRequest`. Generic question gets generic answer.

Comment: So I just notices why I get the error. I had Logger, on small caps. However, I'm still not getting the logs on the server side

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59585277/7215091

Comment: @Cooper What do you mean with the problem bieng in the Javascript tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me this way:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title><?= content ?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <h1><?= content ?></h1>
   <div id="output"></div>
   <form>
   <input type="type" name="first" id="first" value="Laurence">
   <input type="button" id="subButton" value="submit">
   </form>
   <script>
   window.onload=function() {
   var output = document.getElementById("output");
   var first = document.getElementById("first");
   document.getElementById("subButton").addEventListener("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     output.innerHTML = first.value;
     var myData ={"first":first.value};
     console.log("hello");
     google.script.run.doUpload(myData);
   });
   }
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check your view/executions

Comment: Yes.  Look at them in view/executions`Dec 21, 2020, 5:12:10 PM Info {first=Laurence}
Dec 21, 2020, 5:12:10 PM Info I was called!`

Comment: I'm not getting the logs. I get  a message saying that there is no function executing on the editor. (I already copy pasted your code)

Comment: Look at them in view/executions

Comment: Yeah, thats what I'm doing. I dont know why but now im getting null on the log [20-12-21 18:11:14:243 CST] null
[20-12-21 18:11:14:245 CST] I was called!

Comment: Okay, check this out. I'm not getting it on the editor, but I am getting it correct in the dashboard